# what is the meaning of : do you ever..?

Tags: sentence-combination

What is the meaning of  "do you ever?" is it to ask about frequency or habit?
*Do you ever watch a movie?* 
a. How often do you watch a movie? or
b. Is watching a movie your habit?

can we answer:
yes, i do,    no, i don't,  no, she doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I would say that questions with *ever* have more to do with asking how often something happens (that is, frequency) rather than asking if something is a habit. More precisely, you want to know weather something happens to any possible extent. For the purposes of better understanding, it might help to mentally substitute the adverb *ever* whenever you hear it with the phrase *at all*. For example:

> Do you **ever** watch movies? (Do you watch movies **at all**?)
>
> Do you **ever** go out? (Do you go out **at all**?)

Answers to these types of questions should probably be a bit more detailed than simple replies with *yes, I do* or *no, I don't*:

> — Do you ever watch movies?
>   — I do. On occasion, though. I'm not a bit movie fan.